# JupyterHub (v0.8.2) Github Authorization not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, jupyter-notebook, amazon-eks, jupyterhub

**Context:**

I have two EKS clusters. "EKS" is AWS managed kubernetes service. I have deployed JupyterHub application to EKS using helm on each cluster. The only difference is that one cluster is running JupyterHub version 0.7.0 and the other is 0.8.2

We use Github auth for JupyterHub. E.g., in our helm chart:

```
auth:
  admin:
    access: true
    users:
    - my-github-user
  github:
    callbackUrl: ...
    clientId: ...
    clientSecret: ...
    org_whitelist:
    - my-github-org
  scopes:
  - read:org
  type: github
```

**Problem: Authorization appears to be broken for JupyterHub 0.8.2**

The JupyterHub 0.7.0 application is working as expected w.r.t. authorization (it only allows users to log in if they are a member of `my-github-org`.

The JupyterHub 0.8.2 application is not working as expected. It allows *any*  Github user to log in.

The environment configuration is exactly the same, the only difference is the JupyterHub version. Could this be a regression/vulnerability  in JupyterHub 0.8.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a [breaking change](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/blob/6290e23602225b543850f5567c77ddd6c3662297/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1) that was introduced in JupyterHub version 0.8.0.

The config property name for the github organization whitelist was changed from `org_whitelist` to `orgWhitelist`.

Very concerning that helm did not validate my config and also very concerning that the default behavior of JupyterHub is to allow the world to access the application when `orgWhitelist` config property is missing.